# Why doesn't typescript narrow this generic type properly?

Tags: typescript

I am using socket.io, so I'm working with an event types object that looks like this:

```js
// these are the possible events. the event name is the key and the event function type is the type
interface Events {
    a: () => void;
    b: (x: number) => void;
}
```

The possible events that the socket can emit are `a` and `b`. When `a` is emitted, it's of type `() => void`, and when `b` is emitted, it's of type `(x: number) => void`.

Now I want to make a map where I store multiple callbacks for each event type.

```js
// this gets the event function type based on the event name
type SpecificListenerType<T extends keyof Events> = Pick<Events, T>[T];

// show that it works
let aa: SpecificListenerType<'a'>; // type is () => void
let bb: SpecificListenerType<'b'>; // type is (x: number) => void

// this is a map that stores a list of functions for each event name
type ListenerMap = {
    [K in keyof Events]: Array<SpecificListenerType<K>>;
};

// initialize the map to empty lists
const listenerMap: ListenerMap = {a: [], b: []};

// show that it works
let aaa = listenerMap['a']; // type is Array<() => void>
let bbb = listenerMap['b']; // type is Array<(x: number) => void>
```

That should allow me to map `a` to a list of void functions with no arguments and `b` to a list of void functions that have 1 number argument.

Now I want to write the function that removes items from this map.

```js
// function to remove one item from the map
const off = <T extends keyof Events>(
    event: T,
    listener: SpecificListenerType<T>,
) => {
  // what can I do here?
  listenerMap[event] = listenerMap[event].filter((registeredListener) => {
    return registeredListener !== listener;
  });
};
```

But I cannot assign to the map because the types don't work out. I thought the `SpecificListenerType<T>` would do the trick here, but I'm not sure why it doesn't. `listenerMap[event]` should resolve to a single function type, no?

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=24&ssc=66&pln=20&pc=49#code/PTAEBcAsFMGdtAQwE4KggDge1rAlgEYA2C0AbtAHbiwB0EMo5V4oliAtgnrAwgNbQAnkkoATPkwrVQAMwCulAMbg8WShCEZuvdJu0AoPNWjJZiJQgCi0mqADeB0M6QAuUAAoAlKAC8APlAyLDwxAG4nFwJ3DwAPd0p5DgJTHwCgkPCDAF8DAxAGHlAAc2g7PWYZBWVVdX0EAkR4CTqK2zZOaANwLQQAZW0lPFk8JQAZHnAqUwAVXoAeGaZYqfFeQSEsWVAbFlhA31AABVH+ed3qWAAaUBn-AG0ZgF0I-LBYSCwAdwZEVjxWF8sMh+LADCRWIhEO4BtAhiNxpNpsg5tp5gByRDo-xhUAFHraUBFbx+QLBULgsqgAjRUCw+GjCawVazBbogjY3H43pE3hxBJJFLINJkzJ5fGQIpFRCgDiIDC-VjM4FwJCgIiTUBbOSKFRqSi8WTApgWSBSFgdLjdHlMlnIACy8r8DkiznuAGkiRoNtqLjQnu4AILIZCIITzenDRlIyistHu-w4nKvArGAF4RAagBeaEYcoV4CwTA4GB66smYKU6mZ5eZyMdGHctvrTsO9mhoHuTxutK72RT70+PygfyJgOBoMpkKhzo1ddjDvl90x6JeeLABJ0oGDofDJPS5LE-in1Jps5jpgby45a+5hKKO7D835bEFqVJGVCx7eOpq+ogRaoBwWAUFqsZjtAHByMgWBQXo+YGFWBqsFs2yHIsyyrGI6zCL6tj7B4rrmtQ7gzFcRFznaMKDFGiLznG0CLP45Eii6zgFF8kCjkoiAaAAkqAYhFjAqAAPyRJRLYYPclTgE8570Yu0myU8tAjEQUzIB4HioMUSKoGIzYLqxjguKAqDgPIyAaLp+nQIZF7IKAACEviHJJC4RM42ReBE-ZAA)

Comment: I believe you have to assert as `as ListenerMap[T]` behind the filter call, since the filter function infers the type from the single value (SpecificListenerType<T>) and returns that as an array (SpecificListenerType<T>[]), which is not the same type as the one required (ListenerMap[T]). 

Filter types:
`filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];`

Comment: Using `listenerMap[event] = listenerMap[event].filter(/* ... */) as ListenerMap[T];` does make it work. I understand why the filter call returns type `Array<SpecificListenerType<T>>` and that `listenerMap[event]` is of type `ListenerMap[T]`. What I don't understand is why those 2 types are different. They're both based on the same `T` and they are the same as far as I can tell. If I look at `ListenerMap[T]`, based on the index signature it looks like it _has_ to be `Array<SpecificListenerType<K>>` where `K` is the same as `T`. So then I can't tell why those 2 types are different.